# Set CSS Class in HTML.TextBoxFor in VB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've seen the other posts referencing C# syntax do do this, but I can't find how to do it using VB.NET.  I swear I'm daft.  I keep trying different variations that I think would work but I'm missing it.

C# Syntax is:

```
Html.TextBox("title", Model.Title, new { @class = "txt" })
```

How do I do that in VB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
New With {.class = "txt" }
```

Comment: Close enough for me. Thanks so much! 

Actual code that worked was just had to drop the @

New With {.class = "txt" }

Comment: Cheers -- I know in C# I have to escape the class keyword, but I wasn't sure in VB.Net.